# Why does keycloak-client-adapter connect on http?

Tags: wildfly, reverse-proxy, keycloak

I am running a JEE app on a Wildfly server behind an Apache reverse proxy. Using the keycloak-client-adapter it connects to a Keycloak server also behind a apache reverse proxy. Both reverse proxies terminate the SSL connecion and connect to the Wildfly server by http.

When I am opening the JEE app, I am redirected to Keycloak and after I have entered my password I am also redirect to my app - all on SSL through the reverse proxy. But then I get a 403 - the reason for this: The App Wildfly tries to connect to Keycloak to validate the token on http. This is neither allowed ("ssl-required": "all" in keycloak.json and setup in realm) nor is http active at all.

From the app wildfly server.log

```
Adapter requires SSL. Request: http://www.domain.tld/myapp/
```

I have setup the reverse proxy of Keycloak according to the documentation, .well-known/openid-configuration looks good - all URLs are https

keycloak.json

```
{
  "realm": "myrealm",
  "auth-server-url": "https://sso.domain.tld/auth",
  "ssl-required": "all",
  "resource": "myresource",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "secret"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 443,
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

Settings of the reverse proxy for the app

```
ProxyPreserveHost    On

ProxyPass /myapp http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp https://www.domain.tld/myapp
```

Anyone an idea how to force https on the validation? That should be the last step to get the setup running.